# Java Mockito stuck at doReturn of singleton method

Tags: java, input, mocking, jline

I have a singleton class to help me reading input from the console:

```
public class IOHelper {
    public org.slf4j.Logger logger = Logger.logger;

    //JLine
    public ConsoleReader cr;

    private static IOHelper instance;

    private IOHelper(){
        {
            try {
                cr = new ConsoleReader();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static synchronized IOHelper getInstance(){
        if (instance == null){
            instance = new IOHelper();
        }

        return instance;
    }
```

The code which I'd like to test refers to it as:

```
String in = IOHelper.getInstance().cr.readLine();
```

Then my test class:

```
class Test {

    private static NetworkCommunicator networkCommunicator;
    private static IOHelper ioHelper;

    @BeforeAll
    static void setUpClass() throws Throwable {

        ioHelper = spy(IOHelper.getInstance());
        doReturn("1").when(ioHelper).cr.readLine();

        networkCommunicator = spy(NetworkCommunicator.class);

        doNothing().when(networkCommunicator).connectToServer();
        doNothing().when(networkCommunicator).connectToOtherServer();
    }
```

My test gets stuck on the `doReturn("1").when(ioHelper).cr.readLine();` line as if it actually executed the `cr.readline();` part. My stacktrace points towards the method `private native int read0() throws IOException;` found on FileInputStream. The comments suggest it blocks if no input is available.
I want to replace the method `readLine()` on my console, so when my CLI asks for an input, my test can "fake" that input.

edit: the call stack of the 2 interesting threads:

```
"main@1" prio=5 tid=0x1 nid=NA runnable
  java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
     blocks NonBlockingInputStreamThread@1437
      at java.io.FileInputStream.read0(FileInputStream.java:-1)
      at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:207)
      at jline.internal.NonBlockingInputStream.read(NonBlockingInputStream.java:166)
      - locked <0x67d> (a jline.internal.NonBlockingInputStream)
      at jline.internal.NonBlockingInputStream.read(NonBlockingInputStream.java:135)
      at jline.internal.NonBlockingInputStream.read(NonBlockingInputStream.java:243)
      at jline.internal.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:257)
      at jline.internal.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:194)
      at jline.console.ConsoleReader.readCharacter(ConsoleReader.java:2147)
      at jline.console.ConsoleReader.readCharacter(ConsoleReader.java:2137)
      at jline.console.ConsoleReader.readBinding(ConsoleReader.java:2222)
      at jline.console.ConsoleReader.readLine(ConsoleReader.java:2463)
      at jline.console.ConsoleReader.readLine(ConsoleReader.java:2374)
      at jline.console.ConsoleReader.readLine(ConsoleReader.java:2362)
      at jline.console.ConsoleReader.readLine(ConsoleReader.java:2350)
      at com.mypkg.Test.setUpClass(Test.java:43)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-1)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
      at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
      at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:389)
      at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
      at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeAllMethods$5(ClassTestDescriptor.java:228)
      at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor$$Lambda$162.715378067.execute(Unknown Source:-1)
      at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:40)
      at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeAllMethods(ClassTestDescriptor.java:227)
      at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.before(ClassTestDescriptor.java:151)
      at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.before(ClassTestDescriptor.java:61)
      at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.lambda$execute$3(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:80)
      at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$$Lambda$134.398690014.execute(Unknown Source:-1)
      at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
      at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:77)
      at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.lambda$null$2(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:92)
      at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$$Lambda$137.1353170030.accept(Unknown Source:-1)
      at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184)
      at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175)
      at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)
      at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
      at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
      at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
      at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151)
      at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174)
      at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
      at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418)
      at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.lambda$execute$3(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:92)
      at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$$Lambda$134.398690014.execute(Unknown Source:-1)
      at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
      at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:77)
      at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:51)
      at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:43)
      at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:170)
      at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:154)
      at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:90)
      at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:62)
      at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
      at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
      at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)

"NonBlockingInputStreamThread@1437" daemon prio=5 tid=0xf nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
     waiting for main@1 to release lock on <0x67d> (a jline.internal.NonBlockingInputStream)
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:-1)
      at jline.internal.NonBlockingInputStream.run(NonBlockingInputStream.java:275)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Extending this question: I have some methods which asks the user multiple inputs (eg. updating some settings). Am I correct to think that the best approach would be to refactor the settings to a method which takes arguments and test only this new method? Is there a solution where I could just pass down a series of strings to the test to press when any method is trying to read from the `ConsoleReader`? I thought of using `Robot` but how can I make sure that it passes down the keystrokes in a correct order if the reading is not done by the test rather than the underlying logic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you're mocking the wrong thing.  You're wanting to play with the `ConsoleReader`'s returns.  So a couple of options:

---

Move to use some `getConsoleReader()` method on your `IOHelper` class, which you can then mock out - you'll need to make sure that the `IOHelper` class also accesses this via this method.  E.g.

```
private final IOHelper mySpy = spy(IOHelper.getInstance());

@Before
public void setup() {
    final ConsoleReader mockCR = mock(ConsoleReader.class);
    // Any mockery on your mockCR you need.
    // doReturn(...).when(mockCR).readLine();, etc.
    doReturn(mockCR).when(mySpy).getConsoleReader();
}
```

---

Modify the cr field to be a mock.  E.g.

```
private final IOHelper ioHelper= IOHelper.getInstance();

@Before
public void setup() {
    final ConsoleReader mockCR = mock(ConsoleReader.class);
    // Any mockery on your mockCR you need.
    // doReturn(...).when(mockCR).readLine();, etc.
    ioHelper.cr = mockCR;
}
```

I'd warn against this case though; I can't see a reason to have your `ConsoleReader` be `public` (or not be `final`), and this just makes that a requirement.  You can always use some helper library to mess with the field even if it's private.  spring and apache-commons-lang3 both provide this type of utility.

---

Use Powermock to fiddle with the constructor of `ConsoleReader`:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(IOHelper.class)
public class IOHelperTest {
    @BeforeClass
    public static void setup() {
        final ConsoleReader mockCR = mock(ConsoleReader.class);
        // Any mockery on your mockCR you need.
        // doReturn(...).when(mockCR).readLine();, etc.

        PowerMock.whenNew(ConsoleReader.class).thenReturn(mockCR);
    }
}
```

---

Finally, you could modify your `IOHelper` class to take a `ConsoleReader` as a constructor argument, and simply provide the `mockCR` from all the above approaches to that (and make it not `private`).

Comment: The first approach sounds very reasonable to me, however I'm still missing something:

`ConsoleReader cr = spy(ConsoleReader.class);
        doReturn("1").when(cr).readLine();
        doReturn(cr).when(ioHelper).getConsoleReader();`

however when I check in the evaluate expression, `IOHelper.getInstance()` will have a normal cr on it, and `ioHelper.getConsoleReader()` has the spy instance. As if I had a broken singleton pattern applied and the test instantiates IOHelper separately.

Comment: That is because you have created a spy _around_ the singleton instance.  This spy (in a very simplified view) simply subclasses the `IOHelper` and overrides the `getConsoleReader` method to return your mock.  The field is still the un-mocked one; however the accessor to it (`getConsoleReader()`) has been 'mocked' out.

Comment: from a best practice perspective is it acceptable then to provide a method to override the instance of my singleton (in this case with my spy instance) or it defeats the purpose of the singleton pattern and I should try to further refactor the code?